# Static initialization order of inline variables in single TU

Tags: c++, inline, static-variables, initialization-order, inline-variable

I'm aware this question has been asked many times, but this seems to be a slightly different variation which I can't figure out.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <cstdio>

struct TestValue;

inline const TestValue* v_ptr = nullptr;

struct TestValue {
    static const TestValue v1;

    TestValue() {
        v_ptr = this;
        printf("TestValue Initialized at %p\n", this);
    }
};

struct CallTest {
    CallTest() {
        printf("CallTest Initalized at %p\n", this);
        printf("v_ptr = %p\n", v_ptr);
    }
};

const inline TestValue TestValue::v1{};
const inline CallTest ct{};



int main() {}
```

I am using C++17 or later, which adds support for extern, static initialized inline variables. I am trying to understand the guarantees around initialization order when using the inline specifier "out of line". Notice that  `v1` is declared as a static variable of TestValue, then defined inline later, but before `ct`. Surprisingly (to me at least), using Clang 14.0.3, the program prints:

```
CallTest Initalized at 0x404059
v_ptr = (nil)
TestValue Initialized at 0x404068
```

If I move `v1` out of `TestValue` such that it is declared *and* defined in the same line just before `ct`, I get the expected output:

```
TestValue Initialized at 0x404059
CallTest Initalized at 0x404068
v_ptr = 0x404059
```

I am reasonably confident in my understanding of the standard that this second example is guaranteed to print TestValue first. But what about the first case?

I wasn't sure about the legality of forward declaring `v1`, then defining it inline later, but that alone seems OK: https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.inline#note-2

As for the ordering, my understanding is that `v1` and `ct` should be "partially ordered": since they are inline https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.dynamic#1

Then, since at least one of them is partially ordered (and the other is not unordered), they are initialized in the order of their definitions: https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.dynamic#3.1

Perhaps I'm misreading the definition of partially-ordered and unordered? Is `v1` not partially-ordered since the inline specifier comes later in the definition - ie. the ordering only applies to inline at the declaration? In this case I still don't see how it would become unordered; the other possibility is ordered which works. Also specifying inline is needed to fix ODR violations, so it appears to be doing *something*. (I discovered this error from the above situation but where `TestValue` and `CallTest` and their respective definitions were split across multiple headers, the `CallTest` header including `TestValue`).

I also find that GCC respects the definition order of `v1` and `ct` while as above, Clang always initializes `ct` first.

[Godbolt Link](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGEgMykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCBmABykAA6oCoRODB7evgGp6ZkCoeFRLLHxSbaY9o4CQgRMxAQ5Pn5cgXaYDlkNTQQlkTFxCckKjc2teR22EwNhQ%2BUjSQCUtqhexMjsHOb%2BYcjeWADUJv5uyOP4qGfYJhoAgvcP48ReDscAKpjjAGpiXkwZysj2eYVoC2OaAY4y%2BPwI/28mAAVMcAG4AfRSBGIp38ABFjgwvLRaNjiMDns9Xu8CHC/gDMKcAOwgh7HDnHcZMRzIKECWHfBlI9FcSmgx6c%2BkIxkQFYstlSqWY8l4wkEBB4BTi9lKjkpYhhAhUCDmMxCmUigCSDEyYjwAC9MOhjjzTmYAKwpEwetwMM2kY4arUrHVSkzM/FUyM66k42nHNxiWgWhXPKVJ0kWuVpyV644Go0ms2ZlPw442wj2p0ut3mL0%2Bv0BoOahSh/yK/OFwTFsxmFU4tXuhu%2B/19wMD4jtzsciNR0ExjtUx7Q2HgyEWxGA6Vb9ggNFi1lznWrunr8KJ5OphwRqyLtnLp6PI3HFhMMI529zjhrWicD28H4HBaKQqCcG41jWFyGxbEyew8KQBCaD%2BawANYgP4GgAHRJMyZgAJxcMyiT%2BAAbJIZhcB60h/hwkiAchoGcLwCggBoiHIWscCwDAiAoKgLApHQcTkJQaCCcJ8TAFwlF8HQBBxKxEDRIx0RhE0ACenAIeJbCCAA8gwtBacBvBYG%2BRjiKZpD4MQ3SOGiPyMZgqjdF4CmMUaNSMRC0TEJpHhYIxOJ4Cw2k/nwBjAAovx4JgADu%2BkpIw4UyIIIhiOwUhpfIShqIxuhmPohjGJBlj6Hg0SsZAayoNiWSsRwAC0VxnPipiWNYZgaMcTUAOrJixNT2VkLgMO4nhtHoIQLGUFR6GkGR1Nkk3TAUS1ZIMc0jFw1S1L0cxTO0e0jfUcxbcM8S7dykyrcdN3zKUl0SGsCgwdseg4pgOw8L%2B/4MdZYEcKoiSkU15HHMAyB8jJWFcMcEAQZ15XHLghAkO6/i7YmAlCfQuJ7GYKy8EhpkrGhGH%2BFh/g07TdN0/onD0aQYUevhOHMhoJH0wzQEgUDLFsRxZOkNxfEbAQKTuaJEDOujhroHo/DpaI4jZcruUqOo1mFaQ8X%2BSk4V/RwAGkHzvBA/p7lS3SqBUMcINgxDUMw2YcMIx4En45jRMk5xawIJgTBYPEcqM3RvBhZI2F4YRpHxwnCfMmbjEC7YQuk1o5OkOhZHU8y%2BH%2BMykiJCRGhmJIHqeuH/gA/zzHC1nou8WLEBIOJeMiRQEAd5JKAGEYUgaOxNC0ApxBKSp1lqcwxAmTpAl6QQhnGYx5klVZIG2SNjmNSBLluR51lebRIG%2Bf5c%2BBTsIEhWF3ARVQUUxXFiXJUBCEaxlavSBrihawVegB6lWRjYXy1Uw51WWo1FqBB0BtQ6lYSw3VeoDVJENfazhZbjSOtNcaF0lhXXWkUFauRjqLWIfg%2Ba11ho9DOv0HB1CMEMD6M0ShO1Zj0LunoB6bCrqvXellRCdkfoRVoqbc2TFgag3BpIKEQDjhSCwthHqiMyo2FRvgIgBMzBY0DJ7Tu2isbE0bihHOlNqY80seHZmrN2aSC4IkWOiQiLD2ZB6QIEi06sXYpnCKrckASxtjLXu%2BMIisB2I7GRciSoKMkEopRvA5ZaLwIrXan9VZZR/rIP%2B%2BUdZ6H1kwQ299jbiNTpwK2kt3LHDtg7aRENDgxMUcoj2uNJKYy4MY3x2dA7BxGGHWiNiQDRywh6ZxZhOYOIIvhCuydPEN28SY7OucqaWKsbRWuKdAYNy6cbMwdcLbbP9qQRyE9RqSCAA%3D%3D)

**Edit**: Another observation in Clang - If I make `v1` and `ct` constexpr (Removing the side effects from the constructors), the address of `v1` is smaller than `ct` - they are initialized in the expected order.

I also realized in the above example that `const inline CallTest ct{}` has internal linkage, while `v1` is external being a static member. I fixed this, and `ct` is still "incorrectly" initialized first. Not sure if this is affects the expected initialization order.

I also ran this test:

```
extern const TestValue v1;

const inline TestValue v1{};
extern const inline CallTest ct{};
```

Which initializes `v1` first. I don't understand why, if `v1` is a static class variable, it would have a different initialization order than as an ordinary extern variable.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this should be fixed in Clang 16: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/f9969a3d28e738e9427e371aac06d71269220123

Demo: https://clang.godbolt.org/z/vMrhTTW8v